# Is it possible to access a member variable of an object if it's in a list?

Tags: arrays, flutter, algorithm, object, oop

Assuming I have the following class named Quotes:

```
class Quotes {
  String quote;
  String author;

  Quotes({required this.quote, required this.author});

}
```

And I have the following code on my main.dart

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<Quotes> quotes = [
    Quotes(quote: 'Quote #1', author: 'John Doe'),
    Quotes(quote: 'Quote #2', author: 'John Doe'),
    Quotes(quote:'Quote #3', author: 'John Doe')
    ];
}
```

Let's say I wanna pass only the "quote" part of the object at index[0] to another variable of type String or anywhere else that would only accept a String as a parameter and not an object type. How would I be able to accomplish that?

Comment: Why can't you use `quotes[0].quote`? (Also, "that would accept ... not an object type" does not make sense since *everything* in Dart is an object.  Presumably you mean specifically "not a `Quotes` type".  Also, the class name for `Quotes` is misleading since it stores only a single quote.)

Comment: That was exactly it, due to my lack of knowledge of arrays I couldn't find the solution. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The answer was very simple (Thank you jamesdlin)

you can access it by using: `quotes[0].quote`